# Characters randomly disappearring from the output of "find"

Tags: shell-script, shell, find

I'm having a really strange behaviour of find, he is "eating" path characters, can't understand why.

This is using a simple shell script to remux some mp4 files using ffmpeg.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

video_remux_dir=/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux

find "$video_remux_dir" -type f -name "*.mp4" -newermt "1990-01-01 00:00:00" -print | while read -r mp4file ; do

        echo "$mp4file"

        mp4file_basename=${mp4file%.*}

        mp4file_basename_out=${mp4file_basename}_out.mp4

        echo "$mp4file_basename"

        echo "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i $mp4file -map_metadata -1 -c copy $mp4file_basename_out && mv -f $mp4file_basename_out $mp4file && touch -t 199001010000.00 $mp4file"

        /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i "$mp4file" -map_metadata -1 -c copy "$mp4file_basename_out" && mv -f "$mp4file_basename_out" "$mp4file" && touch -t 199001010000.00 "$mp4file"


done
```

And here the results:

```
[root@host /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux]# ls -l
total 2326858
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   81050772 Jul 18  2018 1 El habitante del huevo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   88078466 Jul 18  2018 10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  113562985 Jul 18  2018 11 La fiesta del conejo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  106768685 Jul 18  2018 12 Las ciénagas de Crom.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   87797468 Jul 18  2018 13 El bosque musical.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   84534410 Jul 18  2018 14 La torre de Mat-Mor.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   77658927 Jul 18  2018 15 El laberinto de los horrores.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   97850829 Jul 18  2018 16 El navío de los espectros.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  104649374 Jul 18  2018 17 El antídoto de Brich.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   90052253 Jul 18  2018 18 Viaje al país de los Krunis.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  104629388 Jul 18  2018 19 La cueva de las flores.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   79170697 Jul 18  2018 2 Las perlas mágicas.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  111549054 Jul 18  2018 20 Brug, el comesetas.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  103279764 Jul 18  2018 21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   83907134 Jul 18  2018 22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   89014058 Jul 18  2018 23 El regreso de Miedo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  100884376 Jul 18  2018 24 La bolsa mágica.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   83778207 Jul 18  2018 25 Los Iquel.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   87219648 Jul 18  2018 26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   80171207 Jul 18  2018 3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   96901309 Jul 18  2018 4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   84608498 Jul 18  2018 5 El guardián del bosque triste.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  120853125 Jul 18  2018 6 El brujo Chiprel.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   88559155 Jul 18  2018 7 El desierto de Zeth.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  100888377 Jul 18  2018 8 El hijo de Randal.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   93489946 Jul 18  2018 9 La máquina de granizo.mp4 




[root@host /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux]# /home/vicmarto/scripts/avi-mp4-mpeg-remux.sh 
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores_out.mp4 && mv -f big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores_out.mp4 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/15 El laberinto de los horrores.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/15 El laberinto de los horrores
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/15 El laberinto de los horrores.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/15 El laberinto de los horrores_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/15 El laberinto de los horrores_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/15 El laberinto de los horrores.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/15 El laberinto de los horrores.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos_out.mp4 && mv -f g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos_out.mp4 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti.mp4
zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth.mp4
zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth_out.mp4 && mv -f zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth_out.mp4 zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth.mp4
zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/7 El desierto de Zeth.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo_out.mp4 && mv -f big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo_out.mp4 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/11 La fiesta del conejo.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/6 El brujo Chiprel.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/6 El brujo Chiprel
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/6 El brujo Chiprel.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/6 El brujo Chiprel_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/6 El brujo Chiprel_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/6 El brujo Chiprel.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/6 El brujo Chiprel.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna_out.mp4 && mv -f g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna_out.mp4 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/16 El navío de los espectros.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/16 El navío de los espectros
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/16 El navío de los espectros.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/16 El navío de los espectros_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/16 El navío de los espectros_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/16 El navío de los espectros.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/16 El navío de los espectros.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich_out.mp4 && mv -f big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich_out.mp4 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/17 El antídoto de Brich.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/14 La torre de Mat-Mor.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/14 La torre de Mat-Mor
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/14 La torre de Mat-Mor.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/14 La torre de Mat-Mor_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/14 La torre de Mat-Mor_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/14 La torre de Mat-Mor.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/14 La torre de Mat-Mor.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical_out.mp4 && mv -f ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical_out.mp4 ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/13 El bosque musical.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/9 La máquina de granizo.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/9 La máquina de granizo
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/9 La máquina de granizo.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/9 La máquina de granizo_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/9 La máquina de granizo_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/9 La máquina de granizo.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/9 La máquina de granizo.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros_out.mp4 && mv -f ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros_out.mp4 ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/24 La bolsa mágica.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/24 La bolsa mágica
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/24 La bolsa mágica.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/24 La bolsa mágica_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/24 La bolsa mágica_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/24 La bolsa mágica.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/24 La bolsa mágica.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo_out.mp4 && mv -f big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo_out.mp4 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo.mp4
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/23 El regreso de Miedo.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/5 El guardián del bosque triste.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/5 El guardián del bosque triste
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/5 El guardián del bosque triste.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/5 El guardián del bosque triste_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/5 El guardián del bosque triste_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/5 El guardián del bosque triste.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/5 El guardián del bosque triste.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas_out.mp4 && mv -f ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas_out.mp4 ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas.mp4
ig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/2 Las perlas mágicas.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/12 Las ciénagas de Crom.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/12 Las ciénagas de Crom
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/12 Las ciénagas de Crom.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/12 Las ciénagas de Crom_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/12 Las ciénagas de Crom_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/12 Las ciénagas de Crom.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/12 Las ciénagas de Crom.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo_out.mp4 && mv -f g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo_out.mp4 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/18 Viaje al país de los Krunis.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/18 Viaje al país de los Krunis
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/18 Viaje al país de los Krunis.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/18 Viaje al país de los Krunis_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/18 Viaje al país de los Krunis_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/18 Viaje al país de los Krunis.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/18 Viaje al país de los Krunis.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas_out.mp4 && mv -f g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas_out.mp4 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/20 Brug, el comesetas.mp4: No such file or directory
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/25 Los Iquel.mp4
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/25 Los Iquel
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/25 Los Iquel.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/25 Los Iquel_out.mp4 && mv -f /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/25 Los Iquel_out.mp4 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/25 Los Iquel.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/25 Los Iquel.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c copy g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo_out.mp4 && mv -f g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo_out.mp4 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo.mp4 && touch -t 199001010000.00 g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo.mp4
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/1 El habitante del huevo.mp4: No such file or directory




[root@host /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux]# ls -l
total 2354890
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   81050772 Jul 18  2018 1 El habitante del huevo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   88078342 Jan  1  1990 10 La tierra de los Tu-Tuts.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  113562985 Jul 18  2018 11 La fiesta del conejo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff  106768564 Jan  1  1990 12 Las ciénagas de Crom.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   87797468 Jul 18  2018 13 El bosque musical.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   84534275 Jan  1  1990 14 La torre de Mat-Mor.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   77658799 Jan  1  1990 15 El laberinto de los horrores.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   97850685 Jan  1  1990 16 El navío de los espectros.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  104649374 Jul 18  2018 17 El antídoto de Brich.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   90052127 Jan  1  1990 18 Viaje al país de los Krunis.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  104629388 Jul 18  2018 19 La cueva de las flores.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   79170697 Jul 18  2018 2 Las perlas mágicas.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  111549054 Jul 18  2018 20 Brug, el comesetas.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff  103279764 Jul 18  2018 21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   83907134 Jul 18  2018 22 Ruadan, el cazador de guerreros.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   89014058 Jul 18  2018 23 El regreso de Miedo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff  100884244 Jan  1  1990 24 La bolsa mágica.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   83778081 Jan  1  1990 25 Los Iquel.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   87219510 Jan  1  1990 26 La fiesta de Poti-Poti.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   80171207 Jul 18  2018 3 Iris, la princesa del Lago de Hielo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   96901309 Jul 18  2018 4 Orzek, Señor de los Pantanos.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   84608380 Jan  1  1990 5 El guardián del bosque triste.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff  120852993 Jan  1  1990 6 El brujo Chiprel.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 vicmarto  staff   88559155 Jul 18  2018 7 El desierto de Zeth.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff  100888244 Jan  1  1990 8 El hijo de Randal.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff   93489824 Jan  1  1990 9 La máquina de granizo.mp4
[root@host /mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux]#
```

Some files are remuxed, some not. Can't find a patter!

Looking at the multiples "No such file or directory"

What is wrong?

Comment: To save us searching, could you add a list of which ones were missed?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas your title edit *grossly* deviates from the original intent and is misleading, since the characters removed are not random, but always from the start of the path, which suggest that `read` had bit more than it could chew, probably confused by length in bytes vs length in characters (that `ó` from `Edición` is probably the culprit).

Comment: @UncleBilly,  0, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8 bytes are being removed seemingly randomly from the start of each line of the output of `find` (with no observable relation between that number and the number of non-ASCII characters in those lines). `bash`'s `read` has no limit on the size of the line it reads (like in any Bourne-like shell). It reads one byte at a time until it finds a newline, it only needs to decode bytes as characters for the IFS processing here, but that happens after the finding of the line delimiter.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas not from the start of each line; only from some lines -- I may be actually on the wrong path, but I don't see anything like `Overwrite ? [y/N]` from `ffmpeg` in the OP's output (which should've appeared if `ffmpeg` was trying to read from stdin`), and I vaguely remember a similar bug with bash's `read` reading too much.

Comment: @UncleBilly, note the `0` in my list of numbers ;-)

Comment: @UncleBilly, `bash`'s `read` could read too much when it sees the start of a long UTF-8 character. One can tell the length of a UTF-8 character from its first byte. That can be up to 4 bytes (or 6 if bash implements UTF-8 past the new unicode limit to 0x10FFFF). For instance, it could decide to read 4 bytes when it sees a 0xf4 byte, which could read newline and two other characters, but here, each line ends in `.mp4\n`, so there's no scope for that.

Comment: You're tagging with `bash`, but showing a `sh` script? Is that because you're on a system where the `sh` implementation is `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible explanation is that one command in the loop is reading from stdin (which in this case is the same stream that `read` is meant to read from). [As you found out](/a/504643), that would be `ffmpeg` which does allow the user to control the encoding over the keyboard (unless you pass the `-nostdin` option), hence the reading from stdin to get user input.

That's one of the several issues with looping over `find`'s output that way.

Use the:

```
find ... -exec sh -c '
  for mp4file do
    ...
  done' sh {} +
```

standard syntax (where the stdin of `sh` and `ffmpeg` is left unaffected), or one of the other approaches described at [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) which would also remove the problems with file names that contain newline characters (or `$IFS` contains `4` with your approach).

Comment: Thanks, the problem was looping over find's output.  Changing the script as suggested worked.

Comment: @vicmarto, you're welcome. What is not explained though is why `ffmpeg` (or `mv` or another command in the loop) would be reading some random number of bytes from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally found the reason why my original code didn't worked. Problem was `ffmpeg` and how it interacts with `stdin`. More about this can be read here:

- [Shellcheck: SC2095](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2095)
- [I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Found 3 posible solutions:

1. Use the shell syntax proposed before by @StéphaneChazelas
2. Redirect the stdin with `< /dev/null`
3. Use ffmpeg with the [-nostdin](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) option

Answer (score 0):

[not really an answer; it's impossible to format anything in comments]

Notice that the files not found have the leading 6, 7 or 8 chars from `/mnt/zbig` cut off:

```
/mnt/zbig/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/8 El hijo de Randal.mp4  [ok]
...
big/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/19 La cueva de las flores.mp4  [error]
...
g/media/Movies/Edición/@video-remux/21 La fiesta de la Luna.mp4 [error]
```

I strongly suspect there's some multibyte charset / locale bug in `bash`; try running your script with `LC_ALL=C your_script.sh` and see if it makes any difference. Since the bug is not related to `ffmpeg` or other stuff, but only to `read`, you probably can reduce your test case to

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" ... | while read -r f; do
   ls "$f"
done > /dev/null
```

Please also mention (in your question) your distro and `bash` version.

Of course, using `find | read -r` is horrible, but this is not the point of the question, right? And unless this is some simple user error, a bug is bug, whether the code exercising it is exemplary or not.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C` didn't change anything, same error. Nor renaming `Edición` to `Edicion`. This is bash 4.4.23 under FreeBSD 11.2, inside a iocage jail. But you were right about `find | read -r`, this was the problem. Thanks!